# How to decorate a function using two routes using AWS Lambda Powertools Event Handler feature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

How can I use the API Gateway Event handler feature of AWS Lambda Powertools to provide two different paths for the same function?

Normally, I would decorate my function as follows, which would allow me to call it using the `/v2/application/blacklist` path:

```
@app.post("/v2/application/blacklist")
def post_application_blacklist_v2(body: CurrentVersion) -> ForceUpdate:
   ...
```

Is there a way to provide multiple paths for a single function, so that I could call the above function as `/application/blacklist` and `/v2/application/blacklist`?

I have looked at the documentation, and while it supports dynamic routes, e.g. `/order/<id>`, it doesn't seem like I can use wildcards.

https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/python/latest/core/event_handler/api_gateway/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "catch all route" regex as described in https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/python/latest/core/event_handler/api_gateway/#catch-all-routes

so something like this, using a regular python regex, should work (might need to play with it):

```py
@app.post("^/(?:v2/)?application/blacklist$")
def post_application_blacklist_v2(body: CurrentVersion) -> ForceUpdate:
   ...
```

*edit*

depending on your use case, normally I'd recommend setting up a proxy rule at your gateway/load balancer level  to forward the request to appropriate v2 endpoint rather than handling in potentially many function decorators.

Comment: Thank you, just was what I was looking for! Didn't look in that section, since I expected it was a 404 route, matching all non-existing routes

Comment: What's the definition of the *most explicit route*? **We choose the most explicit registered route that matches an incoming event.**

Comment: This issue doesn't _exactly_ answer but provides some really good context https://github.com/aws-powertools/powertools-lambda-python/issues/2962